# Dropbox sometimes chmod's random updated files to 666

Tags: linux, centos, dropbox

I have the website content on the centos 5 server saved in Dropbox. In that way i can easily access them without having to use ftp. However sometimes it happens that Dropbox chmod's random updated files to 666. This causes the error: "this file is group writeable" Why does it do that and how should i prevent it? Should i maybe create a cron script that looks for chmod 666 files and automatically corrects them? Still that would be a lousy fix though....

Comment: Here's your solution:
http://superuser.com/questions/549591/how-to-preserve-ownership-and-permissions-in-dropbox

Comment: Does this happen when you use the dropbox web interface or some other client? Perhaps by "Dropbox chmod's" you mean that the service does this without interaction? Clarify the conditions under which the erratic behavior occurs.